# How to add schema binding to a view in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

I'm trying to create an index in my SQL Server 2008 database.

But I face an error when I uncomment the `WITH SCHEMABINDING`:

```
USE UNIVERSITY
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.Major_Education_Category
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   SELECT CA.CName, MA.MName
   FROM 
     (SELECT M.Major_ID MID , Major_Name MName
      FROM Major M, Registration R
      WHERE M.Major_ID = R.Major_ID) MA,
     (SELECT C.Category_ID CId, C.Category_Name CName
      FROM Education_Category C, Registration R
      WHERE C.Category_ID = R.Category_ID) CA
   GROUP BY 
      CA.CName, MA.MName

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UCI_Major_Id_By_Education_Category
ON dbo.Major_Education_Category (MName)
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UCI_Category_Id_By_Major
ON dbo.Major_Education_Category  (CName)
GO
```

Error:

> Msg 4512, Level 16, State 3, Procedure Major_Education_Category, Line 6
>   Cannot schema bind view 'dbo.Major_Education_Category' because name 'Major' is invalid for schema binding. Names must be in two-part format and an object cannot reference itself.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: Why are you cross joining the derived tables `MA` and `CA`?

Answer (score 5):

The tables in your from clause need to be specified as two part `{owner}.{tablename}`. Unless you know otherwise,  this is most likely to be `dbo`. So try `dbo.Major`, `dbo.Registration`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Putting dbo.TableName.
Changes to:

```
(SELECT M.Major_ID MID , Major_Name MName
    FROM dbo.Major M, dbo.Registration R
    WHERE M.Major_ID = R.Major_ID) MA,
(SELECT C.Category_ID CId, C.Category_Name CName
    FROM dbo.Education_Category C, dbo.Registration R
    WHERE C.Category_ID = R.Category_ID) CA
```